# Django filter by two parameters

Tags: python, django

I want to filter by two parameters. I have this:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(
             Q(category__in=self.request.GET.getlist("category")) &
             Q(brand__in=self.request.GET.getlist("brand")))
        return queryset
```

But this works only if two filters are chosen(otherwise it returns nothing). I want my program to filter by one filter if only one is chosen and filter by two parameters if two are chosen. How can I do that?

Comment: The answers here are fine, but if you're doing a lot of filtering like this, you may want to take a look at [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    if "category" in self.request.GET:
        queryset = queryset.filter(category__in=self.request.GET.getlist("category"))
    if "brand" in self.request.GET:
        queryset = queryset.filter(brand__in=self.request.GET.getlist("brand"))
    return queryset
```

Most methods applied to a queryset will return a new queryset. This allows you to add more parameters as required. As the queryset is lazy, it doesn't actually query the database until you start consuming data so there's no performance overhead to the above either.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
def get_queryset(self):
  kwargs = {}
  if self.request.GET.getlist("category"):
      kwargs["category__in"] = self.request.GET.getlist("category")

  if self.request.GET.getlist("brand"):
      kwargs["brand__in"] = self.request.GET.getlist("brand")

  return Product.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually write model manager for custom query_sets. For more information you can read the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager

```
class ProductQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

def active(self):
    return self.filter(active=True)

def search(self, query):
    lookups = (Q(title__icontains=query) | 
              Q(description__icontains=query) | 
              Q(price__icontains=query) | 
              Q(tag__title__icontains=query))  # (model_name)__(model_field)__(filter)
    return self.filter(lookups).distinct()
```

class ProductManager(models.Manager):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return ProductQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

def active(self):
    return self.get_queryset().active()

def search(self, query):
    return self.get_queryset().active().search(query)
```

In Views.py:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = self.request
    query = request.GET.get('q', None) 
    if query is not None:
        query = query.strip()
        return Product.objects.search(query)
    return Product.objects.featured()
```

---

I hope that will help you. Good Luck